# FFMPEG - getting started

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

this is probably really simple but ... I've downloaded FFMPEG.dll and added it to my C# project.
now what?  how do I access the VideoFileWriter ?

[image: screen capture of my IDE]

Comment: That is not the correct way to "add a dll". You should add a reference to the library used

Comment: thanks Cleptus... its been a while since I had to include a dll.